# Value of "version" in SCIM

Tags: identity, scim

I am creating an implementation of SCIM 1.1 specification in my existing project. The SCIM spec says the following for "version" attribute:
*The version of the Resource being returned. This value must be the same as the ETag HTTP response header.*

In my existing application, no any version of resource (User) is maintained. So my SCIM implementation is not going to support conditional requests, for example, delete only if the version value matches.

So in this scenario, what should be the value of "version" attribute under "meta" of SCIM's core schema.
"version" attribute seems to be mandatory in the specification (it is availabe in all the examples in the spec (http://www.simplecloud.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark ETag as not supported in your Service Provider configuration and use a constant value for the versions (e.g. W/"000000000000001")

Comment: Thanks vschafer! Can't we just keep it as 0 instead of W/"000000000000001" ?

Comment: Sure you can, it was just an example.